# Python - List comprehension causes NameError when assigned to static varible

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am attempting to create a list of all the combinations of strings from two separate lists. Here is my code:

```
class Function:
    all_prefixes = ['arc', 'inv', 'inverse']
    all_sin = ['sin', 'sine']
    all_asin = [x+y for x in all_prefixes for y in all_sin]
```

This generates:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test", line 1, in <module>
    class Function:
  File "test", line 6, in Function
    all_asin = [x+y for x in all_prefixes for y in all_sin]
  File "test", line 6, in <listcomp>
    all_asin = [x+y for x in all_prefixes for y in all_sin]
NameError: name 'all_sin' is not defined
```

The same problem occurs when the code is moved into the initialiser instead of the variables being static. It does not occur when the code is not in the class. I do not have this problem when I run the code with Python 2.7.12. I am currently using Python 3.5.2. 
Help would be much appreciated because this is for a school project and I can't continue without figuring this one out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check the last paragraph in this section: [4.2.2. Resolution of names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names)

Comment: tagged as python3 - this code works just fine on Python 2.7.x